# Fantasy novel with villainous raiders wearing magical animal masks/helmets; one man wipes out an evil patrol by going berserk

Tags: story-identification, novel

There's a book from when I was younger I can barely remember. I would have read it about 15 years ago (2002/3).

I think the front cover was green with a horse and rider on it.

Fantasy, bad guys had magical animal masks/helmets which made them stronger and faster. The bad guys are raiding and destroying villages.

There's a man whose village was wiped out and who joins up with a sort of resistance band of villagers/farmers. The villagers couldn't hurt them until the protagonist goes berserk and kills a patrol of the evil soldiers pretty much singlehandedly. After a few of these battles, where he's the only one seemingly able to kill them due to his berserker rage, he puts one of the helmets on a villager who gains the same abilities as the bad guys (and they can hence fight back).

Comment: Hi there! That's good info already but could you maybe take a look at [thes guidelines on story-id questions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028), see if they trigger any more memories you could [edit] in? Fr instance, any recollection of what the cover looked like?

Comment: **There's a book from when I was younger (it'd be at least 15 years old probably quite a bit older)** No one here knows ***when*** you were 15 years old or older. Try using actual dates, please.

Comment: @Lexible for once, that was actually quite explicit. The _book_ would have been 15 years old at least (counting from today's date), not the asker.

Comment: @Jenayah Ah, I see. Got it, even so: as the question ages relative time becomes increasingly inaccurate (e.g., when someone reads this question 5 years from now).

Comment: @Lexible they could just look at which date it was asked. But we're drifting away from the point ahah ;)

Comment: @Jenayah I think "15 years ago from when this post was written, do the math" is hostile to future readers. Contrast with "Around 2003".